# How to use shouldOverrideKeyEvent to trigger Javascript function

Tags: javascript, android

I'm currently building a simpel app for Android with a webview that loads a page that should be controlled from the app. 
For this, I want to completly override the default keybehaviour, and just call a function with the keycode from the key that is pressed.

For this, I've tried the following

```
public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(BWWebviewClient view, KeyEvent event){

if ((KeyEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){

webview.loadUrl("javascript:getKeyCode(KeyEvent)");
}

return true;
}
```

The problem with this is that KeyEvent in my ifstatement cannot be resolved.

What I want to do is simple catch all keys, disable their default behaviour and call a JS function with the keycode as argument.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

the KeyEvent var doesnt carry from Java to Javascript... what you're using in loadUrl is just a string, and KeyEvent probably exists nowhere in JS.